# What is the difference between всякий and любой?

Tags: перевод

What is the difference between всякий and любой? It seems that they both mean "any, every"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*любой* straight-up means "any"; *всякий* is more along the lines of "every kind of", "all manner of", etc. *всякий* sees a lot more colloquial usage, but when it's occasionally used directly instead of *любой* it actually sounds more bookish and antiquated (*Всякий, кто осмелится войти, понесёт наказание*).

Comment: Just a remark, всякий can also mean 'different'.

Answer (score 5):

As Nikolay Ershov noted before, differences do occur. As an added illustration:

```
     в любое время              всякий раз            каждый раз
      at any time               every time            each time

     любой человек             всякий человек        каждый человек
        anyone                   everyone              everyone

      любой день                всякий день           каждый день
    a day, any day               every day         day by day, daily
```

I think this is self-explanatory.